# replace value in the dataframe with valure from dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe below:

```
          movieName  Year
            Iron Man  2008
  X-Men Dark Phoenix  2014
      Doctor Strange  2007
          Spider-Man  2014
   x-Men First class  2006
     Captain America  2011
```

And i have this dictionary

```
cor_dict = {'Spider-Man':'The amazing Spider-Man', 'X-Men Dark Phoenix': 'X-Men Days of future',
'x-Men First class':'x-Men:The last stand' }
```

I want to replace the name in the df with the value of dictionary Like this:

```
 'Spider-Man'=>'The amazing Spider-Man', 
     X-Men Dark Phoenix' => 'X-Men Days of future'
    'x-Men First class'=>'x-Men:The last stand
```

to get :

```
            movieName          corrected_name  Year
            Iron Man                Iron Man  2008
  X-Men Dark Phoenix    X-Men Days of future  2014
      Doctor Strange          Doctor Strange  2007
          Spider-Man  The amazing Spider-Man  2014
   x-Men First class    x-Men:The last stand  2006
     Captain America         Captain America  2011
```

**NB: They don't have the same order**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.replace()`.

```
df['corrected_name'] = df['movieName'].replace(cor_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
df["corrected_name"] = df["movieName"].apply(lambda x: cor_dict.get(x, x))
```

Prints:

```
            movieName  Year          corrected_name
0            Iron Man  2008                Iron Man
1  X-Men Dark Phoenix  2014    X-Men Days of future
2      Doctor Strange  2007          Doctor Strange
3          Spider-Man  2014  The amazing Spider-Man
4   x-Men First class  2006    x-Men:The last stand
5     Captain America  2011         Captain America
```

Comment: Hi, i used your method by i got a warning : **A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.** how can i fix it please

Answer (score 0):

A map() function can be used to map the lookup dictionary (cor_dict) to the existing column (movieName) or to create a new column by mapping the dictionary keys to the values on column 'movieName'.

```
df['movieName'] = df['movieName'].map(cor_dict)
```

[image: replacing existing column]

```
df['new_movieName'] = df['movieName'].map(cor_dict)
```

[image]